# iOS keyboard won't dismiss after view dissappears

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been looking for a similar questions but so far the answer doesn't fit my purposes. I have a UITableViewController inside A UINavigationController with custom UITableViewCells containing textfields inside. When I click on the textfields they become the firstResponders and when I click return they resign it. So far so good.

My problem is one of these cells is performs a Submit function. After this is done whenever I press the textfields the return button doesn't dismiss the keyboard anymore.

My question is, since I'm not releasing anything, why do these textfields stop listening to the resignfirstresponder message?

**UPDATE:** I finally got this working by setting an UITextfield ivar in the class, making it the first responder whenever the textfield begins editing in :

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
      [textField setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
      focusedTextField = textField;    
  }
```

And calling `[focusedTextField endEditing:YES];` when i press the submit button. Just added this after seeing some answer in SO, but I can't remember the link, sorry.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have declared a method for return(let's say your textfiled is called `textField`) use this code in your method;

```
[textField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];//but this may restric you if you need to use it again
```

But if you use standard return property of the keyboard it may be something related to Apple's restrictions

Comment: but my problem is that it works correctly the first time, it just leaves it when I perform this sumbit function and then it stops working.

Comment: if so take care of not releasing your object just after the method called. define your property as retain( @property (retain, nonatomic) ... )

Comment: Checked that... it is retained. I can't figure out this problem